# how to add "edit" icon to a column cells in Ag Grid?

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I use Ag Grid in my project. Two columns consist of editable cells. I want to add an edit icon to these cells to indicate that they are editable. I tried using
`cellRenderer`
in
`columnDefs`
, but instead of displaying the edit icon, it showed the HTML code
`<span><i class="fa fa-edit">0</i></span>`. How can I fix it?

here is the code:

```
const [columnDefs] = useState([
{
      field: "title",
    },
{
      field: "result",
      editable: true,
      cellEditor: "agRichSelectCellEditor",
      cellEditorPopup: true,
      cellEditorParams: {
        values: ["Pass", "Fail", "Completed", "Not Checked"],
      },
      cellRenderer: function (params) {
        return '<span><i class="fa fa-edit">' + params.value + "</i></span>"
      },
    },
])
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have found, when your cell renderer returns a string, that string gets rendered literally.

There are two things that you can do.

The first is to use a component to render the cell.

The ag-grid documentation has an example of a React cell render component at https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/#complex-cell-renderer-example

The other possibility is to not user a cell renderer at all, and just set 'cellStyle' that includes CSS to render the icon.